# My method to create directories doesn't create folders

Tags: java, directory

It's the first time ever I tried to create a directory and following some links and directions from previous posts of other users I managed to cook up the following method.
But it doesn't work.The condition to trigger this method is 100% certainly triggered. So the error has to be in here. But I cant figure out what I did wrong since I am a first-timer with this.

```
   public void makeDirectory(String path, String nameFolder) {
    File dir = new File(path + "\nameFolder");
    dir.mkdir();
}
```

Thank you for your time

EDIT: 'Doesn't work' means no directory is being created.

EDIT2:
Have been able to make it work thx to Niks Tyagi

```
    public void makeDirectory(String path, String nameFolder) {
    File dir = new File(path +"\\"+ nameFolder);
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: Does "it doesn't work" mean that no directory is created or that it always creates a directory called "nameFolder", since you're passing a static String instead of the `nameFolder` parameter?

Comment: My apologies ,it means that no directory is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void makeDirectory(String path, String nameFolder) {
        File dir = new File(path + "\\nameFolder");
        dir.mkdir();  // Use mkdirs() method for below reason
    }
```

OR

```
public void makeDirectory(String path, String nameFolder) {
        File dir = new File(path + File.separator+"nameFolder");
        dir.mkdir();  // Use mkdirs() method for below reason
    }
```

`mkdirs()` will create the specified directory path in its entirety where `mkdir()` will only create the bottom most directory.

Comment: @BURNS use dir.mkdirs(); in place of dir.mkdir();